# Firebase Value Not Incrementing with Swift?

Tags: database, swift, firebase, increment

I'm creating a top 10 list.  I need values of certain items to have a value and have that value increment every time some one agrees.  It's currently not updating, but trying to add an identical value and immediately disappearing.  Here is my Firebase stack....

```
TopVideos-->
 yWfsla_Uh80-->
   Value: 1
   description: "Download on iTunes : KOR https://itunes.apple.c..."
   imageString: "https://i.ytimg.com/vi/yWfsla_Uh80/default.jpg"
   rank: 1
   title: "EXO_CALL ME BABY_Music Video"
   user: "6ef370d4-a1bd-48ce-9ae0-93d2e20f3bc8"
   videoID: "yWfsla_Uh80"
```

I want to increase the "Value" child/node, but it's not happening. Here's my code....

```
topVideoRef.childByAppendingPath("Value").runTransactionBlock({
                (currentData:FMutableData!) in
                var value = currentData.value as? Int
                if value == nil  {
                    value = 0
                }
                currentData.value = value! + 1
                return FTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
            })
```

I followed the Firebase guide to the letter, but I may be missing something.  BTW...if you know the answer please include how to decrement the value also. Thank you.

***  UPDATE  ***

I'm creating the videoRef like so.....

```
vidRank = Int(self.rankValue.text!)!
let vidArray = ["user" : self.ref.authData.uid, "videoID": self.videoId, "rank": self.vidRank, "title": self.vidTitleText, "description": self.vidDescription, "imageString": self.vidIMG]
let topVideoRef = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("TopVideos/\(self.videoId)")
topVideoRef.setValue(vidArray)
```

Comment: Can you show how you create the `topVideoRef`?

Comment: @DavidEast I've updated the Post.  Also I've tried `value!++` and `currentData.value.updateChildValues`.  Although I may have written them wrong.

Comment: What does the success callback have to say? Is there an error? Is it committed? How did you determine it was unsuccessful? What is the current value in the database? What is the authentication state? What security rules are in place? See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for the answer @Jay.  It gave a bigger understanding of Firebase Data; retrieving and storing.  I was stuck for a while because I got my button to add and then update but it was caught in a continuous loop.  Once I used `observeSingleEventofType` it all came together.  Here is my finished code where I'm initially saving a video for a user then checking if the video is a #1 video and either saving or updating from there...

```
  @IBAction func finalSaveBTN(sender: AnyObject)
    {
        vidRank = Int(self.rankValue.text!)!
        let vidArray = ["user" : self.ref.authData.uid, "videoID": self.videoId, "rank": self.vidRank, "title": self.vidTitleText, "description": self.vidDescription, "imageString": self.vidIMG]
        let videoRef = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("UserVideo/\(self.ref.authData.uid)/Vid\(vidRank)")
        videoRef.setValue(vidArray)

        if self.vidRank == 1
        {
            let findTopRef = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("TopVideos/\(self.videoId)")
            findTopRef.queryLimitedToFirst(1)
                .observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
                    if snapshot.value is NSNull
                    {
                        print("Save")
                        self.clickedButton1()
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        print("Updated")
                        self.clickedButton2()
                    }
                })
        }
    }

    func clickedButton1()
    {
        print("Button1Action")
        let vidArray = ["Value" : 1, "videoID": self.videoId, "title": self.vidTitleText, "description": self.vidDescription, "imageString": self.vidIMG]
        let topVideoRef = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("TopVideos/\(self.videoId)")
        topVideoRef.setValue(vidArray)
    }

    func clickedButton2()
    {
        print("Button2Action")
        let topVideoRef = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("TopVideos/\(self.videoId)")
        topVideoRef.childByAppendingPath("Value").runTransactionBlock({
            (currentData:FMutableData!) in
            var value = currentData.value as? Int
            if value == nil  {
                value = 0
            }
            currentData.value = value! + 1
            return FTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
        })
    }
```

Please leave a comment if something seems off.  BTW, I still need to decrease in value if a #1 Vid already existed.

Comment: If my answer helped you, please accept it :-)  Also, instead of answering your own question, you may just want to add additional information to your question with the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the code by replacing the fields with text, and then created two functions, linked to two buttons on a window

Then ran the code, and it appears to work.

```
func clickedButton1() {

    print("Button1Action")

    let myRootRef = Firebase(url:"https://your-app.firebaseio.com")

    let vidArray = ["user" : "some user id",
        "videoID": "some video id",
        "rank": "some rank",
        "title": "a title",
        "description": "a description",
        "imageString": "an image"]


    let topVideoRef = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("TopVideos/\("vid_id_0")")
    topVideoRef.setValue(vidArray)

}
```

and the second function

```
func clickedButton2() {

    print("Button2Action")

    let myRootRef = Firebase(url:"https://your-app.firebaseio.com")

    let topVideoRef = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("TopVideos/\("vid_id_0")")

    topVideoRef.childByAppendingPath("Value").runTransactionBlock({
        (currentData:FMutableData!) in
        var value = currentData.value as? Int
        if value == nil  {
            value = 0
        }
        currentData.value = value! + 1
        return FTransactionResult.successWithValue(currentData)
    })

}
```

When button 1 is clicked, the initial data is written out.

Each time button 2 is clicked the Value node is incremented by 1.

I am guessing that either you are overwriting the whole node at some point, or there's a onDisconnect attached to Value that's removing it when you quit the app.

OR... it's being set to nil, which will result in what you are seeing. It will have a value then suddenly disappear.

Comment: Please see my solution and comment on validity of code.